# Is there a non-degenerate solution for this PDE on $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry, exterior-algebra

$\newcommand{\tr}{\operatorname{tr}}$
$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$

Does there exist a smooth map $f:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$, which satisfies
$$\tr \big( df \otimes \delta(df \wedge df) \big)=0, $$  such that
$\delta \big( df \wedge df \big) $ does not vanish identically?

Here $\bigwedge^2 df\in \Omega^2\big(\R^3,\Lambda_2(\R^3)\big)$, and $ \delta \big( df \wedge df \big)\in \Omega^1\big(\R^3;\Lambda_2(\R^3)\big)$, where $\delta$ is the adjoint of the exterior derivative.

---

If there is such an $f$ then it cannot be a local diffeomorphism; its Jacobian must vanish at some point. Expanding explicitly

$$ \delta \big( df \wedge df \big)(X)=\sum_i \nabla_{e_i}(df \wedge df)(e_i,X)=\sum_i (\nabla_{e_i} df)(e_i) \wedge df(X) + df(e_i) \wedge (\nabla_{e_i} df)(X)$$
$$ =\Delta f \wedge df(X)+\sum_i df(e_i) \wedge (\nabla_{e_i} df)(X).$$

Thus
$$ 
\delta \big( df \wedge df \big)=\Delta f \wedge df+\sum_i df(e_i) \wedge \nabla_{e_i} df.
$$
We can try to look first for harmonic counter-examples, but I failed doing even that.

---

**Motivation:** This question is a degenerate version of [this unsolved question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/272355/characterising-critical-points-of-ef-int-m-bigwedge2-df2-textvol) about critical points.